# WooCommerce Paypal Form Won't Submit

Tags: ajax, wordpress, forms, paypal, woocommerce

Hey I customized my woocommerce checkout form to post some hidden input values to paypal instead of doing an ajax post but somehow the ajax post is overriding the normal post and sending its own value to paypal. Can someone help me with this issue please. The form is at...
http://www.dreamhomevacationrentals.com/hotels/spanish-modern-retreat/

Click "Availability" on the left and then click "Book Now" and fill in some dummy data to get to the cart page and then click "proceed to checkout" to see the paypal form.

~Alex

Comment: I can't get past the "Submit Booking" page. When I click the "SUBMIT BOOKING" button, it didn't appear to do anything. Then I scrolled to the top and saw a "_You failed to provide 2 fields. They have been highlighted below._" message, but all fields were filled in, and nothing was highlighted. Are there supposed to be two date fields, perhaps? I saw the calendar, but no date fields.

Comment: Yep, you have to select 2 dates. Thanx for taking the time to look into this for me!

Comment: Nevermind. I was able to fix the issue myself. Thank you.